# Timeout issue with Nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I am hosting and wordpress site on digital ocean with 16gb mem and 4 cores connected with https://moss.sh/ to manage the site.

The issue I am facing my site goes down very frequently and I got 502 and 504 errors.
When I looked into nginx errors. I got:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0w9l4.png) in Nginx error and
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3hJo.png) getting this.

Can someone help me on this?

I tried restaring it and changing timeout setting nginx config.